# Может сервер отправить подключенному клиенту какие нибудь данные?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, сервер, client

Вопрос вот в чем.
К серверу обращаются клиенты (из браузеров по AJAX запросам). Можно как то через админку (PHP) отправить данные определенному клиенту? Ну к примеру предупреждение,сообщение?
А то получается клиент обратился к серверу и ждет ответа, сервер ответ отправил (найдена или нет информация нужная клиенту по условию запроса).

Может я не очень понятно спросил?
К серверу подключены 100 юзеров, по запросу я знаю их айпи, порт. Можно как то 56 юзеру отправить сообщение с админки или как то еще?

Comment: Ну так - записывайте в базу сообщение с указанием, кому. Когда клиент подключится ajax, то ему будет отдано сообщение.

И да, Вы очень непонятно спросили, перепишите вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть авторизованный пользователь на сайте, есть и его идентификация. Например через авторизационную cookie или значение в session. Учитывая это, лучше использовать функцию, которая будет проверять сообщения для пользователя на сервере:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
       $.get( "example.php", function(data) {
           if (data != '') alert(data);
       }
    } , 5000);
 });
```

Для этого примера надо подключать последний jquery.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: Голосую за этот ответ. Считаю он больше соответствует ситуации задавшего вопрос, чем ответ про вебсокеты.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотри про вебсокеты, при подключении пользователя, можно будет сохранить сессию, чтото что поможет его идентифицировать на стороне сервера. И со стороный сервера можно будет отправить в любой момент любый данные, и на клиенте их обработать. Это лучше чем Ajax запрос, потому что ajax требует действия о0т пользователя либо запроса по таймеру.

Comment: Я там пообщался на других форумах. Есть сервера на node.js, типа js на стороне серовера, я почитал про технологию и не вьехал. Получается что бы решить мой вопрос, проще на js написать функцию, которая будет к примеру каждые 5 сек. посылать серверу AJAX запрос типа ЕСТЬ ДЛЯ МЕНЯ ЧТО ТО? Ну и если есть то данные уходят. Но еще посмотрю про websoccets, в ПХП есть же функции для работы с ними?

Comment: Да, ПХП умеет работать с веб сокетами. Как мне кажется это как раз то, что вам надо для решения данной проблемы. Альтернативно можно было бы заморочится с Message Queue, но это не совсем то...

Comment: Чисто формально это конечно правильный ответ. Но также понятно, что человек задающий вопрос его не осилит. Вебсокеты это новый уровень сложности и требует, кроме умения программировать, еще и административного доступа, т.к. понадобится создать демона.

Поэтому незачёт ;) Для типичных сайтов с их 10 посетителями в день ответ слишком хороший.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы Вы подробнее сказали, для чего это нужно, было бы проще.
Общение клиент-сервер, как правило, происходит по инициативе клиента. Поэтому если Вы хотите отправить ему что-то типа "Надо заплатить еще", то это можно сделать, например, после авторизации. А если надо сделать что-то типа чата, то лучше использовать ВебСокеты, с их помощью сервер может послать сообщение клиенту.
В общем, решение зависит от задачи.

Comment: Дело в том что всегда клиент что то запрашивает у сервера, а может сервер запросить или как то отправить клиенту данные (сообщение) без запроса клиента. Технологии js на стороне сервера сложноваты пока что для меня (Денвер), хотя очень интересны.